# Not receiving AWS Certificate Manager email on office 365 using AWS Route53 MX record

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, amazon-web-services, mx-record, amazon-route53

I have a domain, which I bought from GoDaddy, but later on transferred to AWS. I use OFfice365 for my email, and have found the domain keys for it, which I put into the MX record for my hosted zone like below:

```
0 <domain-key>.mail.protection.outlook.com.
10 <other-domain-key>.mail.protection.outlook.com.
```

The problem is, once I request an SSL certificate from AWS Certificate Manager, it sends me an email to five standard email addresses, none of which I own. I'd rather it sent me an email to the address that my MX record in Route53 points to.

How do I make it send a validation email to that email address?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the whois information for your domain, to point to som email address that you have access to.

Comment: When I lookup my domain on whois.com, it shows the correct MX record, i.e., the same one as that listed on my Office365. I'm still not getting the email from AWS

Comment: Whois records have nothing to do with MX records. Check the email contacts you have listed for the domain. These are **not** MX records. Look in your domain registration settings.

Comment: The contact email for my domain is listed as public, but it won't show up in the Whois. Any idea what the reason might be?

Comment: What is the domain in question?

Comment: the domain ends in a dot io, and I called GoDaddy yesterday, only to find out that it was a problem on their end.